# Reach n-th successor of a vertex in a branch

Tags: java, jgrapht, digraphs

I created a digraph using the jgrapht library. I use the `successorListOf()` method to access a vertex's successor, but I'd like to be able to reach the n-th successor of a given vertex (which are Point objects in my case). My digraph has two branches (named B and C here). I made a simple and shorter code to make it easier:

```
public static DirectedGraph<Point, DefaultEdge> directedGraph = new DefaultDirectedGraph<Point, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
public static Point startPoint = new Point(2, 6, "S");
public static Point firstPoint = new Point(2, 7, "A");
public static Point secondPoint = new Point(2, 8, "B");
public static Point thirdPoint = new Point(2, 9, "B");
public static Point fourthPoint = new Point(2, 10, "B");
public static Point fifthPoint = new Point(3, 7, "C");
public static Point sixthPoint = new Point(4, 7, "C");
public static Point seventhPoint = new Point(5, 7, "C");


void setup ()  {
  directedGraph.addVertex(startPoint);
  directedGraph.addVertex(firstPoint);
  directedGraph.addVertex(secondPoint);
  directedGraph.addVertex(thirdPoint);
  directedGraph.addVertex(fourthPoint);
  directedGraph.addVertex(fifthPoint);
  directedGraph.addVertex(sixthPoint);
  directedGraph.addVertex(seventhPoint);
  directedGraph.addEdge(startPoint, firstPoint);
  directedGraph.addEdge(firstPoint, secondPoint);
  directedGraph.addEdge(firstPoint, thirdPoint);
  directedGraph.addEdge(firstPoint, fourthPoint);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
public static ArrayList<Point> pointList = new ArrayList<Point>();
public static class Point {

  public int x;
  public int y;
  public String iD;
  public  Point(int x, int y, String iD) 
  {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.iD= iD;
  }
  @Override
    public String toString() {
    return ("[x="+x+" y="+y+" iD="+iD+ "]");
  }

  @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 71 * hash + this.x;
    hash = 71 * hash + this.y;

    return hash;
  }



  @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) 
  {
    if (this == other)
      return true;

    if (!(other instanceof Point))
      return false;

    Point otherPoint = (Point) other;
    return otherPoint.x == x && otherPoint.y == y;
  }
}
```

I'd like to add an edge between the firstPoint and each point of the "B" branch, and instead of having:

```
directedGraph.addEdge(firstPoint, secondPoint);
  directedGraph.addEdge(firstPoint, thirdPoint);
  directedGraph.addEdge(firstPoint, fourthPoint);
```

I'd like to use:

```
for (Point successor : Graphs.successorListOf (directedGraph, firstPoint)) {
        if (successor.type.equals("B") {
               directedGraph.addEdge(firstPoint, successor);
        }
}
```

But here I can only reach the first successor of the branch B. How can I reach the successor of the successor etc, in the case of n-th successor ? The number of vertices in the B branch may change, that's why I'm looking for a way to do this automatically instead of Point by Point.

How could I do this ?

On the drawing,1 would be my startPoint, 2 would be my firstPoint, and then there are two branches which would be my B & C branches

[image: On the drawing,1 would be my startPoint, 2 would be my firstPoint, and then there are two branches which would be my B & C branches]

Comment: Do `A` vertices connect to `B` vertices?  Is this what defines a "successor"?

Comment: Can you provide an image for how does your graph look like ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen When I add an edge using 'directedGraph.addEdge(firstPoint, secondPoint); ' secondPoint will be the successor of firstPoint. It's always the point at the end of the parenthesis which is the successor of the point at the beginning of the parenthesis. So the only point A is the starting intersection of the B and C branches

Comment: @CMPS I've added a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the following code, but it's not tested and you might need to modify it to fit your requirements.

This code is running a DFS (depth first search) to a predefined depth using the variables and instances you used in your provided examples.

```
public void getSuccessor(DirectedGraph<Point, DefaultEdge> graph, Point point, String type, int depth) {
    List<Point> visitedPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    _getSuccessor(graph, point, visitedPoints, type, depth);
}

private void _getSuccessor(DirectedGraph<Point, DefaultEdge> graph, Point point, List<Point> visitedPoints, String type, int depth){

    if(depth == 0)
        return;

    // Mark node as visited
    visitedPoints.add(point);

    // Loop on all its successors
    for(Point successor : Graphs.successorListOf (directedGraph, point)){

        // If node not already visited
        if(!visitedPoints.contains(successor) && successor.type.equals(type)) {
            directedGraph.addEdge(firstPoint, successor);
            _getSuccessor(graph, successor, visitedPoints, type, depth-1);
        }
    }
}
```